# How to check whether a POJO's fields are 100% thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, pojo

I want to find out whether a class has any non-thread safe fields so that I won't cache them in my factory.

I have written a sample code to test whether a class has potential fields that are not thread safe.

```
final class ObjectStateChecker {

    public void isStateful(@NotNull Class<?> objectType) {
        for (Field field : Arrays.asList(objectType.getDeclaredFields())) {
            System.out.println("Field: " + field.getName());
            int modifiers = field.getModifiers();
            System.out.println("Modifier: " + modifiers);
            if (!Modifier.isFinal(modifiers)) {
                System.out.println("Field " + field + " is final.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Field " + field + " is not final.");
            }
        }
    }

    private class Student {
        private String name;
        private final int age;

        private static final int SOME_VALUE = 1;

        private Student(String name, int age) {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public int getAge() {
            return age;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ObjectStateChecker objectStateChecker = new ObjectStateChecker();
        Student student = objectStateChecker.new Student("Ram", 23);
        objectStateChecker.isStateful(student.getClass());
    }
}
```

How can I enhance the isStateful() method? The goal is to find if the `Class<?>` has any potential non-thread safe fields so that I won't cache them.

**Update:**
Apart from the checking of public synchronized method, is there anything that I have to consider? I think all final and static fields are thread safe except if they are collections that are not synchronized.

I think there must have been some libraries that have done something similar to this. Any references to such libraries is also useful. I am aware of Dependency Injection containers. Is there any such that container has such useful code examples that I can use?

Comment: You can check in addition, if all public methods are synchronized, all fields are safe.

Comment: What's the problem/what's wrong with the above code?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I am not sure about the all possible conditions to check.

Comment: @Vitaly Thank you. Apart from the checking of public synchronized method, is there anything that I have to consider? I think all final and static fields are thread safe except if they are not collections  that are not synchronized

Comment: Maybe this topic help you: [static-analysis-tool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942658/static-analysis-tool-to-detect-multithreading-problems-deadlocks-race-conditio)

Comment: @BRS What do you mean by "thread safe"? You should start with that. It's very hard to define this in a useful way. Note that having, for example, all public fields of a class synchronized, does not mean that I cannot write a multi-threaded race condition involving that class. But given a narrow enough definition of "thread safe" you may be able to make something.

Comment: Yep, "thread safe" is really a meaningless term unless you define the context, what fields might be modified, what fields must be maintained in sync with each other, etc.

Comment: @HotLicks So, in general if I find any fields except some supported loggers, it would be not safe to cache the instance of that object. Am I correct?

Comment: Since I have no idea what your "cache" is going to do, I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

A POJO can't be thread safe.  A POJO is just data, and thread safety is not a property of data alone:  Thread safety is a property of the methods that access the data.  And note,  when I say "methods" I mean the *entire set* of methods.  One method can't be thread safe if another one is not.

Thread safety is all about protecting *invariants*.  An invariant is a boolean test that you can run against the data that must always be true.  An example would be, if your program was a Monopoly game, then the total amount of cash in the bank and in all of the player's hands must always add up to the same fixed amount.

Often it is not possible for a method to do its work without temporarily *breaking the invariant* (i.e., take money out of one player's hand, and then add it to another player's hand).

If one thread can create a temporary condition that other threads must not be allowed to see, then you must use *mutual exclusion* (i.e., `synchronized` blocks) to prevent the other threads from seeing it.  The method that does the temporary damage must do it inside a `synchronized` block, *AND* all of the other methods that must not be allowed to see the temporary damage must also be in `synchronized` blocks whenever they *look* at the data.

When you've synchronized all of the methods so that no method can see a temporary bad state that was caused by any method called in any other thread, *THEN* your whole program will be thread-safe.

---

P.S.:  A class can be called "thread-safe" when there is no possible way for one thread to see an instance of the class in a bad state (i.e., broken invariant) while some other thread is modifying the instance.